# Why is the feasible set of utility values (in bargaining problem) convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, game-theory, expectation

Let $S := \{x \in \Bbb{R}^n \mid x \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\}$ be the set of mixed strategies. For a bimatrix game with pay-off matrices $A$, $B$ we denote $C := \{ (u, v) \mid \exists (x,y)\in S\times S: u = x^TAy, v = x^TBy\}$ and refer to $C$ as the feasible set.

How do you prove that $C$ is convex? That is, for any convex combination of "achievable" values of expected pay-offs there exists a mixed strategy "implementing" this combined value?

*Edit:*

As Michael Greinecker pointed out (see comments below), this is not true in general case. I have read this statement in [Game Theory by prof. Guillermo Owen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/469850.Game_Theory), Chapter IX, page 201.

Having read it once again, it is formulated for *correlated mixed strategies*. Is it already true with this condition or still too general? Any ideas for a proof/counterxample?

Comment: Well, you can't. Unless the players can condition on some common coordination device, the set can fail to be convex. The classic [Bach or Stravinsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_sexes_(game_theory)) game gives an easy counterexample.